# For loop to write data to file Java

Tags: java, loops, writer

I need to implement a method called `saveWorksToFile` according to the Javadoc in the code. The format of the output written to the file should be the following this pattern:

[image]

where ARTIST_NAME is the name of the artist, NUM_WORKS is the number of works
of that artist, and WORK_1, WORK_2, etc. are the toString representations of
each of that artist's works.

The last work should not have a line separator after it.

If an artist has no works, then the first three lines of the above format should
be written, where the “-----” line has a line separator after it.

And this is the code I have:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class Artist {

    static class Work {
        String name; // e.g. "Mona Lisa"
        int yearCreated; // e.g. 1506
        String medium; // e.g. "Oil on poplar panel"

        public Work(String name, int yearCreated, String medium) {
            this.name = name;
            this.yearCreated = yearCreated;
            this.medium = medium;
        }

        public String getName() { return name; }
        public int getYearCreated() { return yearCreated; }
        public String getMedium() { return medium; }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return name + "|" + yearCreated + "|" + medium;
        }
    }

    private String name; // e.g. "Henri Matisse"
    private List<Work> works = new ArrayList<>();

    public Artist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addWork(Work work) {
        this.works.add(work);
    }

    /**
     * Writes the toString representation of each of this artist's works to the
     * given writer. Also writes header lines containing the artist's name and
     * number of works.
     *
     * If an IOException occurs, the message "IOException occurred" should be
     * printed to System.out.
     *
     * @param writer writer to write this artist's works to
     */
    public void saveWorksToFile(Writer writer) {
        // write your code here
        try {
            BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);  
            buffer.write(this.name);            
            buffer.newLine();
            buffer.write("works: " + this.works.size());
            
            buffer.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("IOException occurred");
        }
    }
}
```

I got these errors:

```
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Vincent van Gogh[newline]works: 0[newline]-----[newline] expected:<...nt van Gogh
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Vincent van Gogh[newline]works: 0[newline]-----[newline] expected:<...nt van Gogh
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Vincent van Gogh[newline]works: 0[newline]-----[newline] expected:<...nt van Gogh
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Claude Monet[newline]works: 2[newline]-----[newline]Bridge over a Pond of Water Lilies|1899|Oil on canvas[newline]Impression, Sunrise|1872|Oil on canvas expected:<...laude Monet
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Claude Monet[newline]works: 2[newline]-----[newline]Bridge over a Pond of Water Lilies|1899|Oil on canvas[newline]Impression, Sunrise|1872|Oil on canvas expected:<...laude Monet
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Henry Matisse[newline]works: 1[newline]-----[newline]Woman with a Hat|1905|Oil on canvas expected:<...nry Matisse
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Henry Matisse[newline]works: 1[newline]-----[newline]Woman with a Hat|1905|Oil on canvas expected:<...nry Matisse
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Henry Matisse[newline]works: 1[newline]-----[newline]Woman with a Hat|1905|Oil on canvas expected:<...nry Matisse
=> org.junit.ComparisonFailure: The expected value is: Claude Monet[newline]works: 2[newline]-----[newline]Bridge over a Pond of Water Lilies|1899|Oil on canvas[newline]Impression, Sunrise|1872|Oil on canvas expected:<...laude Monet
```

I have difficulties on making a new line, I tried both `\n` and `newLine()` method but it doesn't work. And also showing the number of works on the list should be correct. And for the loop, I think I should use for loop in this case to loop over the art works.

Any hints/ help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is my code for method `saveWorksToFile`. It is the only part of the code in your question that I changed. (Notes after the code.)

```
public void saveWorksToFile(Writer writer) {
    try {
        writer.write(this.name);
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        writer.write("works: " + this.works.size());
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        writer.write("---");
        writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
        boolean first = true;
        for (Work work : works) {
            if (first) {
                first = false;
            }
            else {
                writer.write(System.lineSeparator());
            }
            writer.write(work.toString());
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException occurred");
    }
}
```

You are not meant to wrap the `Writer` parameter in a `BufferedWriter`. In general, for any method, you usually should not need to cast the parameter. Hence, in the above code, I use only the methods of class `Writer`. Also note that I do not close `Writer` since that should be left to the code that invoked method `saveWorksToFile`.

In order to write a line separator, I call method `lineSeparator` of class `java.lang.System`.

In order to print all the artist's works one per line, I use a loop.

In order to ensure that the last entry in the artist's list of works is written without a line separator, the first work is written without a line separator and every subsequent work is written with a preceding line separator.

Here is a method I wrote to test the above code. It uses class `java.io.StringWriter` which is a subclass of `Writer` since class `Writer` is abstract and has no public constructor. In general, you cannot instantiate an abstract class. You need to use a concrete subclass. I use `StringWriter` so as to be able to print its contents easily to the screen. You can use class `java.io.FileWriter` if you want to write to an actual file.

```
/**
 * import java.io.StringWriter
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Artist artist = new Artist("Vincent van Gogh");
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    artist.saveWorksToFile(sw);
    System.out.print(sw);
    System.out.println();
    artist = new Artist("Claude Monet");
    Work work = new Work("Bridge over a Pond of Water Lilies", 1899, "Oil on canvas");
    artist.addWork(work);
    work = new Work("Impression, Sunrise", 1872, "Oil on canvas");
    artist.addWork(work);
    sw = new StringWriter();
    artist.saveWorksToFile(sw);
    System.out.print(sw);
    System.out.println();
    artist = new Artist("Henri Matisse");
    work = new Work("Woman with a Hat", 1905, "Oil on canvas");
    artist.addWork(work);
    sw = new StringWriter();
    artist.saveWorksToFile(sw);
    System.out.print(sw);
}
```

This is the output I got when I ran the above `main` method.

```
Vincent van Gogh
works: 0
---

Claude Monet
works: 2
---
Bridge over a Pond of Water Lilies|1899|Oil on canvas
Impression, Sunrise|1872|Oil on canvas
Henry Matisse
works: 1
---
Woman with a Hat|1905|Oil on canvas
```

Comment: I don't understand why I still got similar error as my code...`The expected value is: Vincent van Gogh[newline]works: 0[newline]-----[newline] expected:<...an Gogh`, this is the error I got when running your code in the system.

Comment: @HY2000 if you want me to debug your code, then you need to post a [mcve] so that I can run it and debug it. It looks like you are using some kind of unit testing framework like [JUnit](https://junit.org/junit5/). Is that correct? You didn't post the code you run in order to test the code in your question. Feel free to edit your question and post the code that causes the error output you posted in your question.

Answer (score 1):

you can use json format to save your data easily and orginized like this

```
public void saveWorksToFile(OutputStreamWriter writer) {
    // write your code here
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonObject.put("ARTIST_NAME",this.name);
        jsonObject.put("NUM_WORKS",this.works.size());
        for (int i=0;i<works.size();i++) {
            jsonObject.put("work_" + i, works.get(i).toString());
            // you can save work as a byte array or json string so you could easily import the data back
        }

        BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        buffer.write(jsonObject.toString()+"\n");
        buffer.close();
    }
    catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        System.out.println("IOException occurred");
    }
}
public Artist readFromFile(File file){
    Artist artist = null;
    FileReader fileReader = null;
    String line= null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    try {
        fileReader = new FileReader(file);

        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
        
        line = bufferedReader.readLine();


        while (line != null){
            line += "\n";

            JSONObject jsonObject  = null;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(line);

                String name = jsonObject.get("ARTIST_NAME").toString();
                int works_num = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.get("NUM_WORKS").toString());
                // here you can import the works as a string.


                artist = new Artist(name);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            line = bufferedReader.readLine();

        }

        bufferedReader.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return artist;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I'm not allowed to use JSON format. I can only write with those imported libraries and no extra methods.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is that you separate classes, sometimes it is difficult to figure out problems. I separated them like this.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


public class Artist {

    private String name; // e.g. "Henri Matisse"
    private List<Work> works = new ArrayList<>();

    public Artist(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void addWork(Work  work) {
        this.works.add(work);
    }

    public void saveWork(){
        try{
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new FileWriter("path where want to save"));
            writer.write(this.name);
            writer.newLine();
            writer.write("works: " + this.works.size());
            writer.newLine();

            this.works.forEach(work -> {
                try {
                    writer.write(work.name);
                    writer.newLine();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });

            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

public class Work {
    String name; // e.g. "Mona Lisa"
    int yearCreated; // e.g. 1506
    String medium; // e.g. "Oil on poplar panel"

    public Work(String name, int yearCreated, String medium) {
        this.name = name;
        this.yearCreated = yearCreated;
        this.medium = medium;
    }

    public String getName() { return name; }
    public int getYearCreated() { return yearCreated; }
    public String getMedium() { return medium; }



    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + "|" + yearCreated + "|" + medium;
    }
}



public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Work work1 = new Work("Fast1",2019,"ss");
        Work work2 = new Work("Fast2",2019,"ss");

        Artist artist = new Artist("Artist_Tom_Cruise");
        artist.addWork(work1);
        artist.addWork(work2);

        artist.saveWork();
    }
}
```